# Understanding implementation of Extended Euclidean algorithm

Tags: haskell, euclidean-algorithm

After some experimentation and search, I came up with the following definition:

```hs
emcd' :: Integer -> Integer -> (Integer,Integer,Integer)
emcd' a 0 = (a, 1, 0)
emcd' a b = 
  let (g, t, s) = emcd' b r
  in (g, s, t - (q * s))
    where
      (q, r) = divMod a b
```

- What's the meaning behind this expression `t - (q * s)` ?

I've tried to evaluate it by hand; even though I arrived at the correct result `(1, -4, 15)`, I can't see why that expression returns the value of `t`.

There is a famous method for calculating `s` and `t` in `as + bt = gcd(a, b)`. In the process of finding the gcd, I get several equations.

By reversing the steps in the Euclidean Algorithm, it is possible to find these integers `a` and `b`. Those resulting equations look like the expression `t - (q * s)`; however, I can't figure out the exact process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `(q, r) = divMod a b`, we have the equation

```
a = qb + r
```

and because of the recursive call, we have:

```
tb + sr = g
```

Substituting `a-qb` for `r` in the second equation, that means

```
tb + s(a-qb) = g
tb + sa - qsb = g
sa + (t-qs)b = g
```

This explains why `s` and `t - q*s` are good choices to return.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Could you explain this line, please ? "and because of the recursive call, we have: tb + sr = g"

Comment: @F.Zer That's exactly the property you stated in the question... "Calculating `s` and `t` in `as + bt = gcd(a, b)`"